# keyof doesn't return correct type when used with Record

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a list of countries in an object

```js
const CountryCodes = {
  DE: {
    countryCode: 'DE',
    countryName: 'Deutschland',
    phoneCode: 49,
  },
  US: {
    countryCode: 'US',
    countryName: 'United States',
    phoneCode: 1,
  },
  ...
}
```

And an interface for it's content

```js
type CountryCode = {
  countryCode: string;
  countryName: string;
  phoneCode: number;
};
```

If I don't give a type to CountryCodes and get it's keys with `keyof typeof CountryCodes` it returns the correct result which is `'DE' | 'US' ...`

But if i don't give a type there can be errors in this object, someone can add / substract an element. So i want to strictly type CountryCodes object with CountryCode type.

```
const CountryCodes: Record<string, CountryCode> = { ...
```

But with this type, result of the `keyof typeof CountryCodes` is now just `string` as stated in `Record<string, CountryCode>`

Is there a way where I can strictly type this object and still get the keys of countries with `keyof`?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx627w) work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, where the data is first put in a temporary variable which is then assigned to the correct variable and "casted" to the wanted type:

```js
const _CountryCodes = {
  DE: {
    countryCode: 'DE',
    countryName: 'Deutschland',
    phoneCode: 49,
  },
  US: {
    countryCode: 'US',
    countryName: 'United States',
    phoneCode: 1,
  },
}

const CountryCodes: Record<keyof typeof _CountryCodes, CountryCode> = _CountryCodes;
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks.. How I didn't think of this :facepalm:

Answer (score -1):

You can hardcode the valid keys:

```js
type CountryKey = 'DE' | 'US';

const CountryCodes: Record<CountryKey, CountryCode> = {
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are more than 100 countries in the list and new ones can be added. This is not an option in my case