# Type inference for object literal

Tags: typescript

I have the following object declared. I would expect that since I used `as const`, I should be able to get type checking (and autocompletion) for all the keys all the way down. But I get no type inference at all. `const str = ApiConstants.foo` gives no error, and no autocompletion anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

```
type ApiEndpoint = {
  method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';
  queryFn: (...args: string[]) => string;
};

type EndpointGroup = Record<string, ApiEndpoint>;

const ApiConstants: Record<string, EndpointGroup> = {
  user: {
    getUser: {
      method: 'GET',
      queryFn: () => '/api/user/user',
    },
    getUserBalance: {
      method: 'GET',
      queryFn: () => '/api/user/userBalance',
    },
    postSession: {
      method: 'POST',
      queryFn: () => '/api/session',
    },
  },
  admin: {
    findUsers: {
      method: 'GET',
      queryFn: keyword => `/api/admin/user/search/${keyword}`,
    },
    getAdminRole: {
      method: 'GET',
      queryFn: () => '/api/admin/adminRole',
    },
    getUserInfo: {
      method: 'GET',
      queryFn: userId => `/api/admin/user/userId/${userId}`,
    },
    getUserBalance: {
      method: 'GET',
      queryFn: userId => `/api/admin/userBalance/userId/${userId}`,
    },
  },
} as const;

export default ApiConstants;
```

Comment: Because you're using `Record<string, EndpointGroup>`. I experienced similar thing and this solved my issue [keyof doesn't return correct type when used with Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70583529/keyof-doesnt-return-correct-type-when-used-with-record)

Comment: I just tested in the Playground and type checking and autocompletion worked totally fine. Also why should `const str = ApiConstants.foo` give an error? You marked the type as `Record<string, EndpointGroup>` so every string is a valid property to access.